# A non-negative measurable function which is strictly positive on some interval

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

I have this question: suppose that $f$ is a function in $L^1 \cap L^\infty$ (the Lebesgue measure is used tacitly) such that $f \geq 0$ a.e. And $f$ is not the zero function a.e.
Does there exist a rectangle such that the essential infimum of $f$ on such a rectangle is strictly positive?

I feel like the answer is negative, since there exist sets of positive measure which do not contain any rectangle. But I am not sure if I am missing something in this reasoning.

Comment: @joshua The question is about an arbitrary $f$ satisfying some conditions. You cannot choose your $f$.

Comment: Of course the answer is trivial for smooth (even continuous) functions. Any counter example must be rather pathological.

Comment: How about the characteristic function of a Cantor set of positive measure?

Comment: @geetha290krm Indeed, of the characteristic function of the complement of such a set. This is exactly what I was thinking about, but I was not really convinced.